# How to remove line separator in navbar Mobile Jquery

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an ios app using phone gap.I want to include a tab bar in my app.For that purpose I have included the following code

```
<div data-role="navbar" class="tabmenu1" data-dividertheme="b" >
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
                    </ul>
 </div>
```

A tab bar appeared with a separator for each item. Is it possible to remove that separator,so that the tab bar will looks exactly like ios default tab bar.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/daMhj/

**CSS:**

```
.ui-navbar li .ui-btn .ui-btn-inner, .ui-navbar li .ui-btn {
    border: 0 solid red !important;
}
```